# Function from a table

Tags: curves

I like to play Blackjack and I am currently learning a new card counting system. I am studying the according betting strategy right now and there are graphs for certain Risks of Ruin. However, to determine  the values I want I would have to estimate them from the graph because there are no equations given for the functions of the graphs.

Can anybody help me determine those functions for the graphs?

This are the graphs:

[image]

And here is a table for the $~5\%~$ - Curve:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline x & f(x) \\ 
\hline 0.5 & 240 \\
\hline 1 & 150 \\
\hline 1.5 & 110 \\
\hline 2 & 75 \\
\hline 2.5 & 65 \\
\hline 3 & 55  \\
\hline 3.5 & 45 \\
\hline 4 & 38 \\
\hline 4.5 & 35 \\
\hline 5 & 32 \\
\hline  \end{array}

I already thought of $~f(x) = k/x~$ where $~k =~ 150~$, but it's very unprecise so I wanted to have a quite exact function.

Comment: Do you realise that there are infinitely many functions that pass through these points? It would be wise to limit the search space to certain functions only. You mentioned
$$
f(x) =\frac{k}{x} 
$$
so this is a good starting point. But perhaps we need a correction term?

Comment: Another way is to do a Langrange or spline interpolation.

Comment: @MattiP. 

I understand what you mean. You can see on the picture how the graphs look like and the function is only important for 0 < x <= 10

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria 

I am not that good at math to understand what that means ^^

Comment: My opinion is that $f(x)=150/x$ is not such a bad approximation. But to get an even closer result, it would be very beneficial to know some theory. Is there any theory behind how the values were obtained?

Comment: Never mind, in this case the solution proposed by Matti P. is better. Basically, Lagrange interpolation is a polynomial going through all points, whereas spline interpolation is a piece-wise polynomial going through all points.

Comment: Well, I can send you the pdf (the book) which I am reading and where the graphs and other things can be found.